# Random Number Generator Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

[image]

If I consider each possibility like a box then the first box would have 2 possibilities then the second box would have one so that it can cancel the first one , then I would get nine out of 36 that is the total number of outputs , the answer I got was 9/36 but the correct answer is 5/16 what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You think that the second output should cancel the first, and this ain't so since outputs $++-+--$ also yield a zero sum, but after that, the appearance of the factor $9$ is a mystery so it is difficult to further explain your mistake.

Comment: I added the number of possibilities in each box , 2+1+2+1+2+1=9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using bionomial distribution to solve this question.

$p( 1) = \frac 36 = \frac12$

As we need 3 output's as 1.

Then,

$q( -1) = 1 - \frac 12 = \frac12$

Now according to bionamial distribution

$P(X=r) = \binom nr × (q)^{n-r} × (p)^r$

Here X = 3 and n = 6.

$P(X=3) = \binom 63 × (\frac 12)^3 × (\frac 12)^3$

$= 20 × \frac 18 × \frac 18 = \frac5{16}$

Comment: Thank you kanwaljit singh .... binomial distribution how could I miss that!!!

Comment: Mine pleasure..